# Why doesn't this CSS Blur work in IE, but works in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

This Blur works well in Chrome, but not Edge or IE.  It seems like a Microsoft bug.  Can someone find what's wrong in my code so that I can get the expected behavior?

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/o3xpez4s/1/

```
<div id="MainBackground">
    <div id="TextBoxArea">
        <div id="BlurDiv"></div>
        <div id="TextDiv">TEXT GOES HERE</div>
    </div>
</div>

#MainBackground {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/700/300);
  height: 250px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#TextBoxArea {
  /* This should float towards the bottom of the MainBackground image */
  /* It should have a clean, non-blurred border */
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  top: 170px;
  left: 60px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
}
#BlurDiv {
  /* This should contain the blurred background image */
  /* The image is moved a bit so that the eyeballs of the image are visible and blurred */
  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  top: -100px;
  left: -50px;
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;

  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/800/300);
  background-position-x: -134px;
  background-position-y: -52px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
#TextDiv {
  /* This just contains text. Text text should not be blurred. */
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Because IE doesn't support `filter`? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 filters do not work in IE 10 — they are not supported. Some older versions of Firefox also don't support filters. 
You can check for support at this link :
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: Thanks.  I read that elsewhere but was confused because I can get the Blur effect to work in Edge if I remove "overflow: hidden", but that causes other display problems.  Since IE really cannot support Blur, then I think I'll solve my problem by replacing my Blur with a gradient or something.

Comment: Yeah gradient can be a solution to it . But specially blur filter always gives a problem in IE due to lack of support i would suggest better to update the IE and check :)